# Draft JS: Atomic Block Floating Component

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

In the Facebook notes, when you upload an image, you get the hover selection of moving that image from either left, right or center. Center basically insert the atomic render to a new block.

What I don't have an idea, is how to render the atomic block if I want it to float left or right. Given the example in the repo, it only shows the `AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock()` function. I would like to have an option to have text beside my Atomic Block something like here in the image.

[image]

I am guessing I should use `moveAtomicBlock` in this, but there's no example that gives me an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `float` or `justify-content` property in the atomic component css works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the figure's css:

float:right;

Try it!